# Holding with no radial specified

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, holding

During my instrument check ride a couple years ago I was given an unpublished hold by ATC at a fix in the approach. For the hold ATC said something to the effect of "... hold west of [fix name] ..." with no radial, course etc. to hold on specified (at least that's the way I remember it from the check ride...I could be misremembering). Ultimately the hold was cancelled before we got there so I was bailed out from my confusion. However, my question is: am I remembering the instructions right? Will ATC give a hold with no course specified? And if so, what is the expected course?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless it is a published holding pattern, ATC should issue, as you show in your question, a "radial," "course," etc. in addition to the direction from the holding fix.

If there is a published holding pattern at the fix, ATC could instruct you to, as an example: "HOLD EAST AS PUBLISHED." (Ref: [AIM para. 5-3-8 b.)](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap5_section_3.html)

The image below is from the  [FAA JO 7110.65AA, paragraph 4-6-4](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/7110.65AA_ATC_Basic_dtd_4-20-23_FINAL.pdf) (the U.S. Air Traffic Control Handbook) regarding the issuance of holding instructions.  *(emphasis is mine)*

[image]

Comment: Most likely I missed the course in his instructions.

Answer (score 2):

From FAA Order 7110.65AA:

> 4−6−4. HOLDING INSTRUCTIONS
>
> When issuing holding instructions, specify:
>
> a. Direction of holding from the fix/waypoint.
>
> b. Holding fix or waypoint.
> NOTE−
> The holding fix may be omitted if included at the beginning of the transmission as the clearance limit.
>
> c. Radial, course, bearing, track, azimuth, airway, or route on which the aircraft is to hold.
>
> [...]

So this information is required.

It does say elsewhere that this can be omitted if it is a published hold. Even then, it instructs ATC to give full directions at pilot request. You can and should (and must, per 14 CFR § 91.123(a)) ask for clarification any time you are uncertain of an ATC clearance.

Comment: Thanks. I probably missed the course in his instructions then.

Comment: @Tom That or an ATC mistake, or the hold was published and you didn't realize it, I suppose.

Comment: Sadly, "published" doesn't always mean "published *on the chart I'm looking at right now*". A holding pattern published for a fix on a low chart might not always show up on a high chart or on an approach chart, or vice versa. Databases tend to help in that regard, but you're still left with needing to confirm what the database pulled up.